# How to detect if using Key or KeyPath

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I just ran into the problem where I was trying

```
[object valueForKey:key]
```

when I should have used

```
[object valueForKeyPath:key]
```

As a quick fix I did this.

```
if ([[sortDescriptor key] rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound ) {
     sectionHeader = [object valueForKeyPath:[sortDescriptor key]];
} else {
     sectionHeader = [object valueForKey:[sortDescriptor key]];
}
```

Is this the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: simply always use `valueForKeyPath:` it will work for single key :)

Comment: Yep... can you write that as the answer? I will mark it correct for you.